# Malformed ProducerConfig kafka-producer-api-0.9.0.0

Tags: kafka-producer-api

I am currently sending compressed messages through Kafka Producer by enabling the compression using following properties:

- compression.type="gzip"
- compressed.topics="Topic_A, Topic_B"

When the kafkaproducer object is instantiated the following list of properties are listed in ProducerConfig object:

```
{compression.type=gzip, metric.reporters=[], metadata.max.age.ms=300000, metadata.fetch.timeout.ms=60000, reconnect.backoff.ms=50, sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.window.factor=0.8, bootstrap.servers=[MyServer_IP:9092], retry.backoff.ms=100, sasl.kerberos.kinit.cmd=/usr/bin/kinit, buffer.memory=33554432, timeout.ms=30000, key.serializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer, sasl.kerberos.service.name=null, sasl.kerberos.ticket.renew.jitter=0.05, ssl.keystore.type=JKS, ssl.trustmanager.algorithm=PKIX, block.on.buffer.full=false, ssl.key.password=null, max.block.ms=60000, sasl.kerberos.min.time.before.relogin=60000, connections.max.idle.ms=540000, ssl.truststore.password=null, max.in.flight.requests.per.connection=5, metrics.num.samples=2, client.id=, ssl.endpoint.identification.algorithm=null, ssl.protocol=TLS, request.timeout.ms=30000, ssl.provider=null, ssl.enabled.protocols=[TLSv1.2, TLSv1.1, TLSv1], acks=1, batch.size=16384, ssl.keystore.location=null, receive.buffer.bytes=32768, ssl.cipher.suites=null, ssl.truststore.type=JKS, security.protocol=PLAINTEXT, retries=0, max.request.size=1048576, value.serializer=class org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.ByteArraySerializer, ssl.truststore.location=null, ssl.keystore.password=null, ssl.keymanager.algorithm=SunX509, metrics.sample.window.ms=30000, partitioner.class=class org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.DefaultPartitioner, send.buffer.bytes=131072, linger.ms=0}
```

**Problem:**

In this list "compression.type=gzip" is clearly set as required but "compressed.topics" is missing. It results in enabling compressions for all topics but I need it on selective ones.

**Findings:**

I debug the code and came to know that in ProducerConfig.java class "compressed.topics" property is not defined due to that when KafkaProducer object is instantiated it does not have the required property.